# SQL Pivot Table with SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to amend the following SQL code into a pivot table. The original data looks like so:

```
PerilCode       B               C           BI
EQ          179166451986    27296144046   9067728654
WS          182394050346    28745459712   9148728654
SL          114374574342    12703142574   293860386
TC          182394050346    28745459712   9148728654
WF          182394050346    28745459712   9148728654
FF          182394050346    28745459712   9148728654
ST          182394050346    28745459712   9148728654
```

The code is below:

```
SELECT
PL.PerilCode,
SUM(ReplacementValueA) AS 'B',
SUM(ReplacementValueC) AS 'C',
SUM(ReplacementValueD) AS 'BI'

FROM [SE-SQLTO-0300].[AIRExposure_London].[dbo].[tLocation] L

INNER JOIN [SE-SQLTO-0300].[AIRExposure_London].[dbo].[tExposureSet] ES ON L.ExposureSetSID = ES.ExposureSetSID
INNER JOIN [SE-SQLTO-0300].[AIRProject].[dbo].[tExposureViewDefinition] EVD ON ES.ExposureSetSID = EVD.ExposureSetSID
INNER JOIN [SE-SQLTO-0300].[AIRProject].[dbo].[tExposureView] EV ON EVD.ExposureViewSID = EV.ExposureViewSID
INNER JOIN [SE-SQLTO-0300].[AIRProject].[dbo].[tProjectExposureViewXref] PEV ON EV.ExposureViewSID = EV.ExposureViewSID
INNER JOIN [SE-SQLTO-0300].[AIRProject].[dbo].[tProject] P ON PEV.ProjectSID = P.ProjectSID
INNER JOIN [SE-SQLTO-0300].[AIRExposure_London].[dbo].[tLocTerm] LT ON L.LocationSID = LT.LocationSID
INNER JOIN [SE-SQLTO-0300].[AIRReference].[dbo].[tPerilSetXref] PSX ON LT.PerilSetCode = PSX.PerilSetCode
INNER JOIN [SE-SQLTO-0300].[AIRReference].[dbo].[tPeril] PL ON PSX.PerilCode = PL.PerilCode

WHERE P.ProjectName = 'Pricing' AND EV.ExposureViewName = 'CAP Maxed'

GROUP BY PL.PerilCode
```

Ideally what I'm trying to get the pivot to look like is like so:

```
     EQ      WS      SL      TC      WF      FF      ST 
 B   179,166,451,986     182,394,050,346     114,374,574,342     182,394,050,346     182,394,050,346     182,394,050,346     182,394,050,346 
 C   27,296,144,046      28,745,459,712      12,703,142,574      28,745,459,712      28,745,459,712      28,745,459,712      28,745,459,712 
 BI      9,067,728,654   9,148,728,654   293,860,386     9,148,728,654   9,148,728,654   9,148,728,654   9,148,728,654
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific SQL may be needed here...)

Comment: I'm using SQL Managment Studio 2012

Comment: The title of your question explicitly says "SUM".  However, your sample data looks like a string concatenation.  What do you really want?

Comment: I added the SUM becuase what I am trying to get to is a SUM of each column ReplacementValueA, ReplacementValueC, ReplacementValueD transposed across rows by perilcode. I'm not sure how to do this but essentially its switching the rows for the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need first unpivot your data, and then pivot it again:

```
SELECT * FROM (/*your  current query here*/) t
UNPIVOT(v FOR col IN([B],[C],[BI])) u        
PIVOT (MAX(v) FOR PerilCode IN([EQ],[WS],[SL],[TC],[WF],[FF],[ST])) p
```

Comment: Brilliant and elegant answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant, but this will do the trick by using the `PIVOT` syntax. Hope it works.

```
;with cteTable as 
(
-- Your query here
), cteTable2 as
(
select PerilCode, 'B' as SecondCol, B as Value from cteTable
union all
select PerilCode, 'C', C from cteTable
union all
select PerilCode, 'BI', BI from cteTable
)
SELECT SecondCol, [EQ],[WS],[SL],[TC],[WF],[FF],[ST]
FROM cteTable2
PIVOT
(
SUM(Value)
FOR PerilCode IN ([EQ],[WS],[SL],[TC],[WF],[FF],[ST])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Hi pcfre, thanks for your help. I'm getting and incorrect syntax on the final line ) AS PivotTable;

Comment: I just added a couple of missing FROM in the second CTE. Let me know if now it works.

Comment: Thanks again for your help but I'm still getting the same error message. It won't let me get past the error on the last line?

Comment: Just tried and it works. Which version of SQL is on your server?

Answer (score 0):

using cross apply also we can achieve

```
declare @t table (Perilcode varchar(2),B BIGINT,C BIGINT,BI BIGINT)
insert into @t(Perilcode,B,C,BI)values ('EQ',179166451986,27296144046,9067728654),
('WS',182394050346,28745459712,9148728654),('SL',114374574342,12703142574,293860386),
('TC',182394050346,28745459712,9148728654),('WF',182394050346,28745459712,9148728654),('FF',182394050346,28745459712,9148728654),
('ST',182394050346,28745459712,9148728654)
;with CTE AS(
select col,col1,col2 from @t CROSS APPLY 
                    (Select Perilcode As Col,B As Col1,'B' as Col2 UNION ALL 
                    SELECT Perilcode As Col, 
                    C As Col1,'C' as Col2  UNION ALL 
                    SELECT Perilcode As Col, BI As Col1,'BI' as Col2  )A(col,Col1,col2)
                    GROUP BY col,Col1,col2)


select P.col2 As Perilcode,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([EQ]AS MONEY),1),'.00','')[EQ],
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([WS]AS MONEY),1),'.00','')[WS],
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([SL]AS MONEY),1),'.00','')[SL],
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([TC]AS MONEY),1),'.00','')[TC],
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([WF]AS MONEY),1),'.00','')[WF],
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([FF]AS MONEY),1),'.00','')[FF],
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST([ST]AS MONEY),1),'.00','')[ST] from (                  
Select col,col1,col2 from CTE)P
PIVOT(MAX(Col1) FOR COL IN([EQ],[WS],[SL],[TC],[WF],[FF],[ST]))P
```